# Can not use compute method for datatable

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have a datatable and when I debug, I see that it is full with correct datas. I am trying to use a compute method but it does not go well. 
I tried

```
Dim xx As DataTable = gelenData.Compute("Sum(H_PERSON_P_NO_543)", "H_PERSON_P_CINS_544 = 'ERKEK'")
```

and this turned me an error like

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'.

When I tried

```
Dim xx As DataView = gelenData.Compute("Sum(Convert([H_PERSON_P_NO_543], 'System.Int32'))", "H_PERSON_P_CINS_544 = 'ERKEK'")
```

or

```
 Dim xx As DataView = gelenData.Compute("Sum(Convert([H_PERSON_P_NO_543], 'System.Int64'))", "H_PERSON_P_CINS_544 = 'ERKEK'")
```

I get this error

> Syntax error in aggregate argument: Expecting a single column argument with possible 'Child' qualifier.

I am really stuck in here for hours and tried too many things but it seems I am missing something. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your first line of code:

```
Dim xx As DataTable = gelenData.Compute("Sum(H_PERSON_P_NO_543)", "H_PERSON_P_CINS_544 = 'ERKEK'")
```

You can't declare xx as a DataTable since it doesn't return a DataTable object, but rather an Int64.

What it actually does is to return the actual "Sum" of your expression.

So if you Think of it like this:

> "Give me the total sum of H_PERSON_NO_543 where the H_PERSON_CINS_544
>   = 'ERKEK'"

And you have the following data (just for example):

```
H_PERSON_NO_543      H_PERSON_CINS_544
      1                 SOMETHING
      3                 ERKEK
      5                 ERKEK
      7                 SOMETHING ELSE
```

And then you run your code, it will return **8** (since there are two rows meeting the criteria, one with the value **3** and one with the value **5**).

When you then try to cast it as a `DataTable` it will simply refuse, since it's a nice `int` and not a `DataTable`.

So, assuming you want to sum up the values from the H_PERSON_NO_543 column in the table your best bet would be:

```
Dim xx As Integer = gelenData.Compute("Sum(H_PERSON_P_NO_543)", "H_PERSON_P_CINS_544 = 'ERKEK'")
```